# How many ways to arrange deck of cards (4 suits from 6 to ace = 36 cards) so that no king comes before any diamond card are there

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, order-theory

So we have 36 cards and we need to find how many ways are there to arrange all the cards so that no king comes before any diamond card.

I have totally no idea how to solve it, I don't understand how to calculate the ways to place all 4 kings to the desired position

Comment: What is a "Tiles card"?

Comment: The rhombus suit. Probably, it's called somehow differently

Comment: In English it's called "diamonds".

Comment: Does $(K\spadesuit) (9\heartsuit) (J\diamondsuit)$ count as a king coming before a diamond card?  Or does "*coming before a diamond card*" only count if the King came **immediately** before the diamond card and was adjacent to it?

Comment: Yes, it counts as king coming before a diamond card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one king of diamonds, $3$ other kings and there are $8$ non-king diamonds.

There are $\binom{36}{12}$ ways to pick the positions for these important cards.

We ignore all other cards and assume only the important cards exist.

Notice that if we look at the important cards there are $8!$ ways to order the non-king diamonds (they have to go at the beginning).

There are $3!$ ways to order the non-diamond kings (they go at the end of the important cards).

---

We can now order all of the other cards in $24!$ ways.

Therefore the answer is $\binom{36}{12}8!\times3!\times24!$

Comment: Why are there only 5 non-king diamonds? I think there are 9-1=8 non-king diamonds

Comment: oh yeah let me fix it./

Comment: Probably you'd like to fix also $27!$.

Comment: Indeed${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This answers if "*no king comes before any diamond card*" is in reference to kings occurring *any distance* before a diamond card.  If the question were as I initially read it as "*no king comes* **immediately** *before any diamond card*" this complicates matters considerably.